# Adding modal view controller to parent-child view controller hierarchy

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I posted a related question to no response but here I'll be less narrow. Basically, I'm using a piece of open-source code to implement a facebook-style, slide to reveal type view. The implementation of this relies on a pattern in which the initial sliding view controller is the application window's root view controller at launch. Then it permits every view controller to get a reference to that sliding view controller through this convenience method:

```
- (ECSlidingViewController *)slidingViewController
{
  UIViewController *viewController = self.parentViewController;
  while (!(viewController == nil || [viewController isKindOfClass:[ECSlidingViewController class]])) {
    viewController = viewController.parentViewController;
  }

  return (ECSlidingViewController *)viewController;
}
```

I think this is where my problem lies. I want to have this slide-to-the-side style menu for a view controller that I present modally. But a modally presented view controller returns null for it's parent view controller. So when I try to get a reference to that root view controller (the initial sliding view controller), I can't. If I push the view controller, it works, but that's not the flow that I want for the application. I thought that if I could add this modal view controller as a child of the presenting view controller, it would work. But when I tried that I got an exception that I was presenting modally a view controller that was already active. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

EDIT: [Here's](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&biw=1353&bih=823&tbm=isch&tbnid=yn6nlxRe46ibHM%3a&imgrefurl=http://iphoneappcafe.com/facebook-updates-its-iphone-app/&docid=nfSRX7iaXgXrNM&imgurl=http://iphoneappcafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Facebook-iPhone-App-Review1.jpg&w=320&h=480&ei=cJiyT-T_IMaRiQKJ8eisBA&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=309&sig=105296724904754695008&page=1&tbnh=149&tbnw=99&start=0&ndsp=24&ved=1t:429,r:6,s:0,i:85&tx=61&ty=36) an example of the kind of thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: could you give a flow of your views graphically or literally..and what you want to perform..when you refer side-by-side etc ..its ambigous

Comment: apologies for ambiguity. Added a link to an image of what I mean by slide to the side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this tool to achieve the same effect and found implementation far, far simpler. http://cocoacontrols.com/controls/iiviewdeckcontroller

Answer (score 0):

From our discussion , the inference can be had that it is a view-base application.So, you will have to add and remove subview from superview as per requirement and for that you will to create a class that keeps a track of the views.Also, instead of presenting the view modally you can have it added as subview like:-

```
[self.view addSubView:viewController.view];
```

you can use `bringSubViewToFront` to bring it to the top.See this [Link to manage it](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-uiview-category-to-manage-z-order-of-views.html)

Comment: No, I'm sorry but that's not it. This is for iPhone, not iPad. And the behavior is different. Two view controllers are initialized, one on top of the other. A pan gesture moves the top view controller to the side, revealing the one beneath. In the facebook app (the example image), when you see that menu on the left, it is a result of sliding the top view controller to the right to reveal a menu view controller underneath.